# Search for a particular file in all the gitlab repositories

Tags: github, gitlab

Simple and very much needed feature, just would like to know if it's possible to search for a particular file in GITLAB  in all the repositories instead of a particular repository.  There's a  huge search icon on the right corner of the GITLAB  which will search corresponding maching repository names BUT NOT the files.

I would like to search for a particular file through all the repositories which I have access to in GITLAB.

Please note that the GITLAB is hosted in the private domain of my organization.  So googling **filename:something.txt**   or  **something.txt in:path**   doesn't work (this was suggested by one of the user in some post for GITHUB).

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's possible using [Advanced Search](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/advanced_global_search.html) feature by enabling Elastic Search [integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/elasticsearch.html).

Once that is configured you can use [Advanced Syntax Search](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/advanced_search_syntax.html) with search filters to find what you need.

For example, you could search the `.gitlab-ci.yml` files of all projects for the text `tags.yml` inside of it typing this in global search bar:

```
tags.yml filename:gitlab-ci
```

Another example to search abc.txt file in all repositories (ensure Group and Project dropdown menu are set to Any) :

```
* filename:abc.txt
```

Comment: not working.. what do u you mean by "once that is configured"?

Comment: I want to search for a particular file.. not  particular string inside the file

Comment: for example.   show me all the repositories which has abc.txt file

Comment: I think you don't have the Elastic Search integration. I edited my answer to point to the documentation and I added an example.

Comment: @NicolasPepinster I tried on gitlab.com, it didn't work? Does it work for you?

Comment: Worth point out for people who seem confused by this answer that this isn't just a simple advanced search. You essentially need to host all the elastic search instances yourself. It will give you what the OP is asking for, but this is an advanced option requiring you to do a lot of integration manually.